# How to pass JSON parameter with $ajax to asmx web service

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asmx

My paramerter as below:

```
var pMaster = '{"tid" : "474", "fid":"2"}';
var pDetail = '[{"recid":5618,"tid":"474","itemid":"1435","nar1":""},{"recid":5619,"tid":"474","itemid":"1203","nar1":""},{"recid":5620,"tid":"474","itemid":"1205","nar1":""}]';
var e = '{PurcMast: ' + pMaster  + ', PurDetail: ' + pDetail + '}';
```

I am calling ajax as below

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/saveValue",
        data: e,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.d);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR) { alert(jqXHR.responseText); }
    });
```

And WebService.asmx code as below:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod]    
public void saveValue(string PurcMast, string PurDetail)
{
    System.Data.DataTable purMaster = Common.CommonFunction.convertJSON2Table(Purchase);
    System.Data.DataTable purDetail = Common.CommonFunction.convertJSON2Table(PurchaseDetail);
}
```

I am getting error as below:

> Uncaught Error.{"Message":"No parameterless constructor defined for type of \u0027System.String\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertDictionaryToObject(IDictionary`2 dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.MissingMethodException"}

Guys please help me, i don't understand what wrong i am doing.

Comment: [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Apologize buddy, i just changed the value to string. I tried it with JSON.stringify() but still same error.

Comment: You don't have "" around *PurcMast* and *PurDetail* props in source JSON. That's invalid JSON.

Comment: Your URL is `url: "WebService.asmx/saveValue"` while the method name is `savePurchase`

Comment: @Alisagar, Updated that also but web service is not being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this on my site. This is what I had to do...

```
// remove the outer quotes so they are json objects then json encode.
var pMaster = JSON.stringify({"tid" : "474", "fid":"2"});
var pDetail = JSON.stringify(
    {"[{"recid":5618,"tid":"474","itemid":"1435","nar1":""}, 
    {"recid":5619,"tid":"474","itemid":"1203","nar1":""},
    {"recid":5620,"tid":"474","itemid":"1205","nar1":""}]);
// then create e by stringify a second time

var e = JSON.stringify({PurcMast: pMaster , PurDetail: pDetail });
```

This worked for me.   You were just creating strings instead serialized json objects.

Comment: In doing this, I ran into a problem with dates.  Dates in the /Date(1234564)/ format were being double escaped and would not deserialize right in the back end.  My first fix was to change the format to yyyy-mm-dd formatted as a string, which worked.  But then I started using the Newtonsoft Json serializer which already put it in that format.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are passing data in wrong way. Try this:

```
var pMaster = '{"tid" : "474", "fid":"2"}';
var pDetail = '[{"recid":5618,"tid":"474","itemid":"1435","nar1":""},{"recid":5619,"tid":"474","itemid":"1203","nar1":""},{"recid":5620,"tid":"474","itemid":"1205","nar1":""}]';

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/saveValue",
        data: {PurcMast: pMaster, PurDetail: pDetail },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.d);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR) { alert(jqXHR.responseText); }
    });
```

Comment: Invalid JSON primitive: PurcMast

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is `url: "WebService.asmx/saveValue"` while the method name is `savePurchase`

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/savePurchase",
        data: e,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.d);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR) { alert(jqXHR.responseText); }
    });
```

I think this should work.

Comment: I have changed. It was my mistake. Apologize. Anyhow, web services is not being called. Somewhere javascript script error show.